# How much leakage current is too much in a transformer?

Tags: transformer, three-phase, leakage-current

[image]

I have a 3-phase transformer with 3 primary windings and 3 pairs of secondary windings. I'm trying to test the isolation between the secondary winding pairs.

To do this I shorted A1, B1, C1 and A2, B2, C2. I used a hi-pot dielectric tester with the positive lead on A1 and negative lead on A 2. The tester output is 180 Hz sine wave.

At only 80 V, I measure leakage current of 2.5 mA between the 'isolated' secondary windings that trips the tester.

When doing the same test between primary and secondary or between primary and chassis, I measure less than 1 mA leakage at 1000 V - a huge difference.

Is there something wrong with the transformer or with my leakage current measurement?

What problems could a leakage between secondary pairs cause?

Update:

Neither the primary nor the secondary windings have been connected in delta.

I thought maybe it could leak through my current meter but it still trips without the meter installed.

[image]
[image]

Comment: At 2.5 mA, something is seriously wrong with either the transformer, the tester or your setup. Please post a photo or schematic of _exactly_ how it's connected.

Comment: How's the construction? I mean, is it something like a combination of three 1P transformers or the windings are wound on a single core? Also, is the delta connection was already made when you bought it or did come with isolated terminals so you could connect them as required (delta or star)? If the latter, show a proper diagram or a photo of how you connected them.

Comment: Rohat, no delta connections installed yet, I added some pictures.

Comment: Please show in the schematic what’s connected and how.